# Android : sort list items by date in listview

Tags: android, listview

I need functionality as shown below, please let me know what listview operation i should make, thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look into this link i think this may helps u.

for this purpose u have to use stickey header list.

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

and u have to sort the data by date vise and give it to the sticky header list.

Comment: thanks, this will help sure

Answer (score 0):

For sort list items by date in listview you should use this approach : [UITable View in android](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/12/iphone-uitable-view-in-android.html)